# Published VHF frequency shown in parentheses on a Sectional Chart. What does this indicate?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, chart-supplement, frequency

Buffalo Niagara International Airport (KBUF) does not have an associated VOR or VORTAC, yet it has a published frequency box that lists a VHF frequency (116.4) in parentheses. Why is this frequency in parentheses and what does it designate? See below:

[image]

Comment: Well, chart supplement says "(H) DME 116.4 BUF Chan 111 N42º55.74´ W78º38.78´ 280º 3.8 NM to fld. 730/0E".  Someone else can surely give a more comprehensive answer though.

Comment: (Looks like you've got your answer now-- maybe-- or at least some ideas for further refining / expanding the question or soliciting more details from the answerer-- )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Complementing William's answer; my go-to for such intricacies is the [specifications](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/iac/) used to create the charts by the Interagency Air Committee. Which here also serves as a formal source that includes the word "parentheses":

> 3.9.3.12.3 [...]
>
> DME facilities shall be shown as illustrated in Appendix 6.
>
> DMEs shall be identified by name, channel, identification letters, Morse code, and paired frequency in **parentheses.**

And from said Appendix 6:

> [image]

As you can see, the whole DME "box" is a perfect match.

Answer (score 8):

[There is a VOR/DME for BUF on that frequency](https://www.pilotnav.com/navaid/faa-1764), BUT [it's either been, or is in the process of being **partially** decommissioned](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2021/11/12/2021-24559/amendment-of-vor-federal-airways-v-31-v-36-v-84-v-252-and-v-510-in-the-vicinity-of-buffalo-ny), leaving just the DME portion.

And when you've got just a DME [you put the frequency in parenthesis.](https://www.boldmethod.com/blog/lists/2021/05/seven-rare-symbols-found-on-vfr-sectional-charts/)

Comment: I'm actually not seeing the explanation of the frequency in parenthesis on your last link-- ?

Comment: @quietflyer - look at item #5 in the last link.

Comment: OK got it.  It is depicted, even if parentheses aren't specifically explained.